# Inconsistent persistence of Global Object

Tags: c#, singleton, global-variables

I'm working on a Cloud-Hosted ZipFile creation service.

This is a Cross-Origin WebApi2 service used to provide ZipFiles from a file system that cannot host any server side code.

The basic operation goes like this:

- User makes a POST request with a `string[]` of Urls that correlate to file locations
- WebApi reads the array into memory, and creates a ticket number
- WebApi returns the ticket number to the user
- AJAX callback then redirects the user to a web address with the ticket number appended, which returns the zip file in the `HttpResponseMessage`

In order to handle the ticket system, my design approach was to set up a Global Dictionary that paired a randomly generated 10 digit number to a `List<String>` value, and the dictionary was paired to a `Queue` storing 10,000 entries at a time. ([Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369446/dictionary-with-item-limit))

*This is partially due to the fact that WebApi does not support Cache*

When I make my AJAX call locally, it works 100% of the time. When I make the call remotely, it works about 20% of the time.

When it fails, this is the error I get:

`The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Meaning, the ticket number was not found in the Global Dictionary Object.

I've implemented quite a few Lazy Singletons in the last few months, and I've never run into this.

Where did I go wrong?

```
//Initital POST request, sent to the service with the string[]
public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    try
    {
        var urlList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(value);
        var helper = new Helper();
        var random = helper.GenerateNumber(10);
        CacheDictionary<String, List<String>>.Instance.Add(random, urlList);

        return random;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}

//Response, cut off where the error occurs
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string id)
{
    try
    {
        var urlList = CacheDictionary<String, List<String>>.Instance[id];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(ex.Message)
        };
        return response;
    }
}

//CacheDictionary in its Lazy Singleton form:
public class CacheDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;
    private Queue<TKey> keys;
    private int capacity;

    private static readonly Lazy<CacheDictionary<String, List<String>>> lazy =
        new Lazy<CacheDictionary<String, List<String>>>(() => new CacheDictionary<String, List<String>>(10000));

    public static CacheDictionary<String, List<String>> Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private CacheDictionary(int capacity)
    {
        this.keys = new Queue<TKey>(capacity);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dictionary.Count == capacity)
        {
            var oldestKey = keys.Dequeue();
            dictionary.Remove(oldestKey);
        }

        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        keys.Enqueue(key);
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[key]; }
    }
}
```

**More Error Detail**

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at ZipperUpper.Models.CacheDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
```

Comment: can you narrow it down tell us what `Key` it did not find..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE The Key is the 10-Digit number created in the POST request by `helper.GenerateNumber(10)`. We know the number is created, because it is returned to us in the AJAX response. However, when we go to the URL with that number, it cannot find it in the dictionary.

Comment: could there perhaps be something screwy with the `URL` can you post what that non working url looks like..?

Comment: Both successful calls and unsuccessful calls are going to the same address with a 10 digit number appended: `/api/zip/4444326331` and `/api/zip/2368252654`. One works and one doesn't. There doesn't seem to be any error creating the number and registering it to the Dictionary, it just randomly is or is not there upon GET

Comment: sounds to me like some data is being lost or compromised could there be something going on with the actual zip process.?

Comment: @DJKRAZE It fails before it even gets there. The dictionary is called to provide the URLs for the zip service, and the URLs are not found as the KEY to their VALUE doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: `var urlList = CacheDictionary<String, List<String>>.Instance[id];`

Comment: silly question but have you tried this 
[Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)

Comment: I haven't, but RegEdit seems to have found it. It was on a 3 server farm. Going to open a different question to resolve communication between machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find it's to do with where you're locating your Global Dictionary. For example, if this was a web farm, and your dictionary was in Session, one instance of your app could access a different Session from another instance, unless the Session state handling was set up correctly. In your case it's in the cloud, so you will need to make provision in the same kind of way for related requests and responses being handled by different machines. Therefore one could send out the key, and another could receive the AJAX redirect but not have that key in its own "global" data.

Comment: Good Point. I went into Azure and confined the machine to one instance and it seems to be working. It's not necessarily a One-in-Three chance scenario, it is a "What are the chances the machine you make the AJAX call to will be the one that picks up the GET call"

Comment: I assume when you make an AJAX call to a machine at its address, you maintain that machine when you move on to the GET request, and this is not the same with a remote call